# OLEDB Source dosn`t receive Sql Statment from Skrip Task

Tags: variables, ssis, qsqlquery, script-task

I have a problem with script task. 
I have a Package where Foreach Loop Container contains Skriptask that creating Sql Statment into Variable. Variable is defined early and contains default value
When after execution SkriptTask I`m trying to create DataFlow (OLEDB source) which has to get SqlStatment from Variable, but actually OLEDB is getting default value from Variable and not the new one from Script.

Is where any options what I miss?

Thanks a lot!

Update:

Case "feed"
                MsgBox("FEED")
                If CStr(Dts.Variables("ExecutionFlag").Value) = "1" Then
                    Dts.Variables("FEED").Value = "SELECT  [SymbolName] ,[Bid],[Ask],[TickTime],[server],[ServerID],[LastUpdate] FROM FEED where cast( " & ColumnDateFilter & " as date)  between '" & FromDate & "' and '" & ToDate & "'"
                    MsgBox(Dts.Variables("ExecutionFlag").Value.ToString)
                ElseIf CStr(Dts.Variables("ExecutionFlag").Value) = "0" Then
                    Dts.Variables("FEED").Value = " SELECT [SymbolName] ,[Bid],[Ask],[TickTime],[server],[ServerID],[LastUpdate] FROM FEED"
                End If

Comment: Questions about code that show no code are difficult to debug at best

Comment: Please post your initial code.

Comment: Actually, I founded the problem - My Variable was named by capital letters  , but CASE was with regular one, so that`s why script code ignored the generated statement